# Design question: longitudinal data from single sampling point?

Tags: panel-data, experiment-design, survey

I've designed a questionnaire and am now wondering what the appropriate term would be to describe the design. Participants complete the instrument once. So in that sense it is not longitudinal. However, they're asked to report on the same measurement (e.g. pain) for several discrete epochs of time in the past. In this sense the data is longitudinal as I have multiple instances of the same measure across time for a single subject. Would this be considered a quasi-longitudinal design?

Comment: Hummm... I'd be shocked if I stumped all you experts here at Cross Validated.

Answer (score 0):

A longitudinal study, by definition, refers to any research strategy where the independent and dependent variables are observed *after* the onset of the investigation and the participants are observed 2 or more times.

Broadly, there are two types of studies that use historical records. A **retrospective cohort study**, also called a historical cohort study, is one where records are used to identity two groups of individuals: those who have been exposed to an independent variable and those who were not exposed. For example, one might study the effects of ionization on cancer risk by studying records of people exposed to nuclear warfare during WWII.

A **case-control study**, also sometimes called a case-referent study, is one where records are used to identify groups of individuals who were exposed to a dependent variable (called *cases*) and individuals not exposed to a dependent variable (called *controls*). The cases and controls are then compared in terms of their previous exposure to some independent variable. For example, one might investigate the relationship between smoking and risk of cervical cancer; a researcher might find individuals with and without cervical cancer, and interview those individuals to determine smoking histories.

If your research strategy includes studying two or more cohorts at the same time, then you have a cross-sectional study. A cohort, in this case, refers to a group of people who share some significant life event. For example, you might study 6-9 year old children living in an urban city and 6-9 year old children living in a rural village.

If you are using self-report to obtain information about people's attitudes, opinions, behaviors, demographics, and other factors, and you collect the data via interview or questionnaire, then that research strategy is a survey. This criteria would include questions that ask about the frequency of some events happening in the past.

Kirk, Roger E. (2013) *Experimental Design: Procedures for the Behavioral Sciences*

Comment: Thanks Nick. I appreciate the answer. I'm afraid it doesn't really answer my question though. Also, I'm a bit confused. You suggest that if you're studying 2 or more cohorts simultaneously you have a cross-sectional study. Yet there are plenty of studies which compare groups using multiple time points collected after study onset.

Our observations were made after study onset of course, but were self-reports of past (repeated) events. Your first point suggests this is not longitudinal. That would mean I have data amenable to repeated measures analyses but non-longitudinal???